# Python package missing when deploying

Tags: python, linux, deployment, package

On my development (Win7) machine, my app runs fine. The folder structure looks like this (the script being run is run.py below):

```
package1/
  __init__.py
  run.py
  ..
```

Inside the app, there are some modules which do stuff like

```
 import app from package1
```

Which works fine.

However, when I try deploying to a linux machine, and run that exact same file, I get an error:

```
  ImportError: No module named package1
```

I looked into the sys.path of both machines when this script is being run. The first two lines of the windows machine are these:

```
C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\IdeaProjects\\PROJ_NAME\\package1
C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\IdeaProjects\\PROJ_NAME
```

Whereas the linux one only has this:

```
/home/username/webapps/PROJ_NAME/package1
```

I recognize the problem is that the second line is missing. But why is it missing? What am I missing? Did I build the folder structure wrong?

Comment: What does `import app; print app.__file__` tell you was imported instead?

Comment: I think the `PROJ_NAME` folder is the only one of those two that should be on the path on either machine.

Comment: @user2357112 that does make sense to me, but then the question is why is it there in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a crappy solution, and I don't like it, but it works.
I added this to run.py

```
# Fixing the python path
import sys
import os

file_location = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
project_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(file_location, os.pardir))
if not project_dir in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, project_dir)
```